# pandas calculate returns batween two dates for multiple data points

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe with the following columns:

| Date | Identifier | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 28/02/2023 | BBA LIBOR USD 3 MONTH | 55 |
| 31/01/2023 | BBA LIBOR USD 3 MONTH | 63 |
| 28/02/2023 | BBA LIBOR USD 1 Month | 32 |
| 31/01/2023 | BBA LIBOR USD 1 Month | 59 |
| 28/02/2023 | MSCI All Country World Index Net Total Return | 16 |
| 31/01/2023 | MSCI All Country World Index Net Total Return | 17 |
| 28/02/2023 | MSCI World Index Net Total Return | 46 |
| 31/01/2023 | MSCI World Index Net Total Return | 12 |
| 28/02/2023 | S&P500 Total Return Index | 11 |
| 31/01/2023 | S&P500 Total Return Index | 45 |

I would like to calculate the percentage return from January to February by (Price<sub>Feb</sub>/Price<sub>Jan</sub>) - 1 and the collapsing to only keep February. This is the end dataframe I'd like to end up with:

| Date | Identifier | Price | Returns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28/02/2023 | BBA LIBOR USD 3 MONTH | 55 | -15.38% |
| 28/02/2023 | BBA LIBOR USD 1 Month | 32 | -45.76% |
| 28/02/2023 | MSCI All Country World Index Net Total Return | 16 | -5.88% |
| 28/02/2023 | MSCI World Index Net Total Return | 46 | 283.33% |
| 28/02/2023 | S&P500 Total Return Index | 11 | -75.56% |

So far I have tried this:

```
(df
    .sort_values(by=['Identifier', 'Date'], ascending=[True, False])
    .groupby(by='Identifier')
    .Price
    .pct_change()
)
```

This kinda works but it places the return on the 31/01/2023 date for all series.

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: add `.shift(-1)` at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what the issue is with the solution you have, but I added couple more steps to give you the dataframe format you are looking for:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'Identifier', 'Price'])

df['Date'] = ['28/02/2023', '31/01/2023', '28/02/2023', '31/01/2023', '28/02/2023', '31/01/2023', '28/02/2023', '31/01/2023']
df['Identifier'] = ['BBA LIBOR USD 3 MONTH', 'BBA LIBOR USD 3 MONTH', 'BBA LIBOR USD 1 Month', 'BBA LIBOR USD 1 Month', 'MSCI All Country World Index Net Total Return',
                    'MSCI All Country World Index Net Total Return', 'MSCI World Index Net Total Return', 'MSCI World Index Net Total Return']
df['Price'] = [55,63,32,59,16,17,46,12]

group_series = (df
 .sort_values(by=['Identifier', 'Date'], ascending=[True, False])
 .groupby(by='Identifier')
 .Price
 .pct_change()
)

df['pct_change'] = group_series
new_df = df.loc[~pd.isna(df['pct_change']), :]
new_df
```

Comment: This seems to work - thanks for the help. I'll check my work laptop tomorrow but I'm not sure what I was doing wrong there. Anyway I marked it as the correct answer.

Comment: Interesting. In my dataset it seems that the sorting of the date with ascending=[True, False] sorts 28/2/2023 first which causes my issue. I think it's because you don't convert Date to dateime.

Comment: This did the trick for me: `group_series = (df.assign(Date=lambda df_: datetime(df_['Date'], dayfirst=True)).sort_values(by=['Identifier', 'Date'], ascending=[True, True]).groupby(by='Identifier').Price.pct_change())`

Answer (score 0):

My percentage change differed from your output

```
   df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'Identifier', 'Price'])
df['Date'] = ['28/02/2023', '31/01/2023', '28/02/2023', '31/01/2023', '28/02/2023', '31/01/2023', '28/02/2023', '31/01/2023']
df['Identifier'] = ['BBA LIBOR USD 3 MONTH', 'BBA LIBOR USD 3 MONTH', 'BBA LIBOR USD 1 Month', 'BBA LIBOR USD 1 Month', 'MSCI All Country World Index Net Total Return',
                    'MSCI All Country World Index Net Total Return', 'MSCI World Index Net Total Return', 'MSCI World Index Net Total Return']
df['Price'] = [55,63,32,59,16,17,46,12]

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Price'] = df['Price'].astype(float)
df['Month'] = df['Date'].dt.month
df['Year'] = df['Date'].dt.year

df=df.sort_values(by=['Identifier', 'Date'], ascending=[True, True])
df['Price_Change'] = df.groupby(['Identifier'])['Price'].pct_change()*100
min_max=df.groupby(['Identifier'])['Price'].agg(['first', 'last'])
#print(min_max)

#print(df)

df = df.loc[~pd.isna(df['Price_Change']), :]
df=pd.merge(df,min_max,on=['Identifier'],how="inner")

print(df)
```

output:

```
 Date                                     Identifier  Price  Month  \
0 2023-02-28                          BBA LIBOR USD 1 Month   32.0      2   
1 2023-02-28                          BBA LIBOR USD 3 MONTH   55.0      2   
2 2023-02-28  MSCI All Country World Index Net Total Return   16.0      2   
3 2023-02-28              MSCI World Index Net Total Return   46.0      2   

   Year  Price_Change  first  last  
0  2023    -45.762712   59.0  32.0  
1  2023    -12.698413   63.0  55.0  
2  2023     -5.882353   17.0  16.0  
3  2023    283.333333   12.0  46.0
```